# angular-ui bootstrap datepicker multiple date selection

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

It seems lite [angular-ui/bootstrap/datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) cannot be configured for multiple date selection.

Is there someone who have implemented a hack or have a good idea where to start modifying the source to enable selection of multiple date in a single datepicker?

Comment: Are you trying to implement multiple, separate datepickers on the same page? Or to have a single datepicker allow the selection of multiple dates?

Comment: single datepicker allow selection of multiple dates

Comment: Did you ask the authors to add such a feature?

Comment: @Mawg no, I ended up using this one instead: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox
Not an angular directive but quite nice anyway.

Comment: I wrote a module that extends UI Bootstrap's Datepicker to select multiple dates. https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect

Answer (score 4):

I've googled for this same answer today and found this:
https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect

I noticed that the project initial commit is newer than this question and maybe you already solved the problem, but the link can be usefull to someone reading this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this plugin: **[MultipleDatePicker](http://arca-computing.github.io/MultipleDatePicker/)**

> MultipleDatePicker is an Angular directive to show a simple calendar allowing user to select multiple dates with a bunch of options to customize it.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker)